# Display error message when using IDisposable interface with another interface

Tags: c#

In my project that I am programming, in the part of using two interfaces simultaneously for a class, I have encountered a problem that is observed error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0738  'Valn' does not implement interface member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'. 'Valn.Dispose()' cannot implement 'IDisposable.Dispose()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'void'.  Server  D:\Project\Server\Logic\Valn.cs 17  Active
```

Also, the structure of the class and interface I created is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyWeb.Server.ClassWithInt
{
    public interface IValInterface
    {
        Task<BindingList<Valn>> ValuationSelect();
        Task<List<ValnState>> ValuationStatusSelect();
        Task Dispose();
    }
    public class ValnMain : IValInterface, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly LosacoDbContext MyMaincontext;
        public ValnMain(LosacoDbContext dbContext)
        {
            MyMaincontext = dbContext;
        }
        public async Task<BindingList<Valn>> ValuationSelect()
        {
            await MyMaincontext.Valns.LoadAsync();
            await MyMaincontext.ValnState.LoadAsync();
            return MyMaincontext.Valns.Local.ToBindingList();
        }

        public async Task<List<ValnState>> ValuationStatusSelect()
        {
            return await MyMaincontext.ValnState.ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task Dispose()
        {
            await MyMaincontext.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I used two methods, in the first method I wrote the desired interface with **:**

```
public class ValnMain : IValInterface, IDisposable
```

and in the second method with a sign **,**

```
public class ValnMain : IValInterface : IDisposable
```

but again an error was observed. Thanks. Please help if possible. I wish you the best.

Comment: The error message is correct: you did not implement `IDisposable`. You need an explicit interface implementation `void IDisposable.Dispose()` because of the name collision with the Dispose method of the other interface. BTW: consider using IAsyncDisposable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Klaus Gütter  I got this error when I used your sample code: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0106 The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item D:******* 39 Active AND Second Error is : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CA1816 Change Valn.Dispose() to call GC.SuppressFinalize(object). This will prevent derived types that introduce a finalizer from needing to re-implement 'IDisposable' to call it. My*****.Server D:***.cs 39 Active –

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that `IDisposable` requires a public method `void Dispose()`, while your other interface requires `Task Dispose()`, methods in interfaces in c# needs to comply to the interface both in name, return value and parameters. Therefore while your Dispose in `ValnMain` satisfies the `IValInterface` interface, it does not satisfy the `IDisposable` requierments.

You may want to use `IAsyncDisposable`, or, should you want to use the interfaces in the OP, you can implement the `IDisposable` Dispose() with an explicit interface implementation:

```cs
    public class ValnMain : IValInterface, IDisposable
    {
        //[...]

        public async Task Dispose()
        {
            await MyMaincontext.DisposeAsync();
        }
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            // your code here, IDisposable is a synchronous interface
        }

    }
```

Hope this will be helpful

EDIT: removed the `public` from the declaration (that will teach me to check in the IDE first before posting code)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mattia Mele  I got this error when I used your sample code:   Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0106 The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item D:\******* 39 Active  AND Second Error is : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CA1816 Change Valn.Dispose() to call GC.SuppressFinalize(object). This will prevent derived types that introduce a finalizer from needing to re-implement 'IDisposable' to call it. My*****.Server D:\***.cs 39 Active

Comment: The first error is my mistake, you don't put `public` in explicit interface implemetations (it's implied), i've edited the post to correct it.
For the second one it's a rule for the implementation of the Dispose() method. I'm not an expert on the subject, but I belive you need to place a call like `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` in the Dispose method. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1816) is a MS page on the issue

Answer (score 1):

An EF Core DbContext implements *IDisposable* and *IAsyncDisposable*. So you have to implement 2 methods with the correct return type:

```cs
public void Dispose() => MyMaincontext.Dispose();
public ValueTask DisposeAsync() => MyMaincontext.DisposeAsync();
```

But I would implement ValuationSelect() and ValuationStatusSelect() in LosacoDbContext. ValnMain has only one field (the DbContext), and all operations are applied to it.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.  I got follow error:  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0738 'Valuation' does not implement interface member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'. 'Valn.Dispose()' cannot implement 'IDisposable.Dispose()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'void'. ****.Server D:\*****Valn.cs 16 Active

Comment: Remove `Task Dispose();` from IValInterface.  ValnMain implements IDisposable in your definition (`ValnMain : IValInterface, IDisposable`), so there is a conflict between this 2 methods. As an alternative, you can write `public interface IValInterface : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable` and ValnMain implements only IValInterface (and implicit IDisposable).